# i want to get the output like this, can anyone help me the logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

input

```
id  nm
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
6   F
7   G
8   H
9   I
10  J
11  K
12  L
13  M
14  N
15  O
16  P


output          
A   B   C   D
E   F   G   H
I   J   K   L
M   N   O   P
```

This is the input and i want output like this

Comment: based on which logic you want this..share your logic too

Comment: pivot on mode 4

Comment: Where is your effort so far? Please edit your question accordingly. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas to improve your question.

Comment: This is something I wouldn't do in SQL. You are showing A with B and C and D, as if they were particularily related, as this is what a row in an SQL result represents. However, what you are actually trying to achieve is merely a space-saving layout. The final layout should be a task for the GUI layer (app / Website), not SQL.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily achieve this using `MOD (%)` and applying `PIVOT` like following.

```
;with cte as
(
  select *, id%4 m from @table
)
select [1], [2], [3], [0] AS [4]
from 
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY M ORDER BY ID) RN , M, NM
  from CTE
) src
pivot
(
  MAX(NM)
  for M in ([1], [2], [3],[0])
) piv;
```

**Full Code :**

```
declare @table table (id int,  nm char)
insert into @table values
( 1,  'A'),(2,  'B'),(3,  'C'),(4,  'D'),(5,  'E'),(6 , 'F'),(7,  'G'),(8,  'H'),
(9 , 'I'),(10 ,'J'),(11, 'K'),(12, 'L'),(13, 'M'),(14 ,'N'),(15, 'O'),(16, 'P')

;with cte as
(
  select *, id%4 m from @table
)

select [1], [2], [3],[0] AS [4]
from 
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY M ORDER BY ID) RN , M, NM
  from CTE
) src
pivot
(
  MAX(NM)
  for M in ([1], [2], [3],[0])
) piv;
```

**Output :**

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D |
+---+---+---+---+
| E | F | G | H |
+---+---+---+---+
| I | J | K | L |
+---+---+---+---+
| M | N | O | P |
+---+---+---+---+
```

**Online Demo :**

[Here](https://rextester.com/HFZ70086)

Comment: This is great solution and easy to execute.